# Syntax for the convergence of random variables

Tags: probability-theory, notation

Can anyone explain the syntax from the following Wikipedia article on the [convergence of random variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables#Definition)?

$$
\begin{array}{ll}
X_{n} \stackrel{d}{\rightarrow} X, & X_{n} \stackrel{D}{\rightarrow} X, \quad X_{n} \stackrel{\mathcal L}{\rightarrow} X, \quad X_{n} \stackrel{d}{\rightarrow} \mathcal{L}_{X}, \\
X_{n} \rightsquigarrow X, & X_{n} \Rightarrow X,  \quad\mathcal{L}\left(X_{n}\right) \rightarrow \mathcal{L}(X)
\end{array}
$$

In particular:

1. What is the squiggly line?
2. What are $d$, $D$, $L$, $L_X$?
3. Why does it say $X_n$ implies X? They don't seem to be statements

Comment: All these symbols are just variants of notation for convergence in distribution. You don't ask "what are these _c_, _o_ and _s_ you need to multiply to get $\cos$", right?

Comment: @Grigory: I really do need to read more carefully

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All of these expressions are just notations for "X_n converges to $X$ in distribution".

1. The squiggly line is really just a notation (a rather strange one) for convergence in distribution.
2. The symbols $d$ and $\mathcal D$ stand for *distribution*, $\mathcal L$ and $\mathcal L_X$ stand for *law*. (One also speaks of "convergence in law" instead of "convergence in distribution".
3. This is also just a notation for convergence in distribution (also a rather strange one); the arrow does not symbolize an implication of statements.

Comment: Oh, I'm feeling quite thick at the moment